# Datatables using JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to load a JSON response from Google Shopping into a table in html formatted using DataTables, the JQuery plugin.

I'm appending the data to the table div but it does not seem to be working.

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Shipping</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Shipping</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script>

        var apiKey = "key";
        var country = "US";
        var apiurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?callback=?";


        $(document).ready(function() { 

          $('#example').dataTable();

            $('.button').click(function (e) {
            $('#example').empty();
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: apiurl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
            data : 
        {
           key: apiKey, 
               country: country, 
               q: $('[name=myanswer]').val()    
            },
            success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
            if (item.product.images.length > 0) // sanity check
            {
                //global variables
                var link = item.product.images[0]['link'];
                var title = item.product.title;
                var gtin = item.product.gtins[0];

                //price
                var currency = item.product.inventories[0]['currency'];
                var price = item.product.inventories[0]['price'];
                var shipping = item.product.inventories[0]['shipping'];

                var listData = "<li>" + title + gtin + price + currency + shipping + "</li>" + '<img title="' + title + '" src="' + link + '" />';

                var dataTable =
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + '<img title="' + title + '" src="' + link + '" />' + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + gtin + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + title + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + currency + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + price + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + shipping + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                        $('#example').append(dataTable).hide().fadeIn('slow');
                        console.log(data)
   }
   });

   }
   });
   });
   });
```

Update: With Larry's help, I've managed to get the data loading into the table. I know this as the number at the bottom is populated. However, the data is not displaying at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #images { padding:0; margin:0; overflow: hidden;}
  #images img { width:200px; height:200px; border:none;}
  td {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
  #example img { width:50px; height: 50px; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" name="myanswer" value="test">
   <input type='submit' class="button" name="submitButton" value='submit'>
</form>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

    var apiKey = "key";
    var country = "US";
    var apiurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?callback=?";


    $(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#example').dataTable();
            $('.button').click(function (e) {

            $('#example').empty();

                e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: apiurl,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data : 
                    {
                        key: apiKey, 
                        country: country, 
                        q: $('[name=myanswer]').val()   

                        },
                    success: function(data) {

                         $.each(data.items, function(i, item){

                            if (item.product.images.length > 0) // sanity check
                            {

                            //global variables
                            var link = item.product.images[0]['link'];
                            var title = item.product.title;
                            var gtin = item.product.gtins[0];

                            //price
                            var currency = item.product.inventories[0]['currency'];
                            var price = item.product.inventories[0]['price'];
                            var shipping = item.product.inventories[0]['shipping'];

                            $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                            title,
                            gtin,
                            price
                            ]);

                            }
                        });

     }
   });
  });



});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is fixed. I forgot to remove the empty method which was forcing the table to show as empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your AJAX call is working and returning data, the proper way to append a row to a jQuery dataTable is not to attempt to edit the underlying HTML but rather to have dataTable add the row through the dataTable API call fnAddData().

There is an [example here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).

Comment: Larry, thanks. I'm pulling the data from Google Shopping API, so where would I put the method?

Comment: You should make the following changes: (1) you do not need to format the data as a table row (dataTable will do that for you), so remove all the code and (2) replace the call to `$('#example').append(dataTable).hide().fadeIn('slow');` with a call to `$('#example').dataTable.fnAddData()` with the arguments as shown in the example I linked.

Comment: Larry, thanks. I have edited my code but now i'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined
$.fn.dataTablejquery.dataTables.js:7365
c.extend.eachjquery.min.js:30
c.fn.c.eachjquery.min.js:24
$.fn.dataTablejquery.dataTables.js:6923
(anonymous function)google-example.php:90
c.extend.eachjquery.min.js:30
$.ajax.successgoogle-example.php:75
bjquery.min.js:124
c.extend.ajax.A.(anonymous function)jquery.min.js:125
(anonymous function)

Comment: Have you correctly constructed the table in the document ready function?  You'll need a base table with a header section to receive the data that you're posting, and it will have to be "initialized" as with a previous call to .dataTable().

Comment: Larry, i've updated my code, please take a look. Really appreciate your help. Now the data is not displaying at all, but it is being loaded into the table.

Comment: Try calling fnDraw() once after updating your table.  I think there's also an optional parameter to fnAddData to specify a redraw, but even if there is you may only want to redraw once, after all rows are added.

Comment: @jcrowson I got the same error. My solution was adding a thead tag to the table. Also see http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3012/error-in-google-chrome/p1 . Of course adding the data with the api is cleaner, but when your stuck with a table then this might be a solution.